# Making array object to be self referencing and dynamic in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem I am trying to resolve. I have an array object which an object inside the array will also be an array object of itself. I want this effect to be more dynamic. This functionality is for different paragraphs level in a document.

Main object:

```
$scope.ParagraphInfo = {
    Id: null,
    SectionId: null,
    Name: '',
    Body: '',
    ToBeDeleted: false,
    Paragraphs: []
};
```

2nd level:

```
$scope.TemplateDoc.ParagraphInfo[$scope.CurrentInfoIndex].Paragraphs.push({
    Id: 0,
    Name: '',
    IsConditional: false,
    IsSubParagraph: false,
    ToBeDeleted: false,
    Body: '',
    Questions: [],
    SubParagraphs: [{
        Id: 0,
        Name: '',
        ToBeDeleted: false,
        Body: '',
        SubParagraphs: []
    }]
});
```

So array object I would like to be more dynamic is the SubParagraphs.
Currently I need to keep track in what level I am at to go 1 level deeper

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: a bit unclear, can you provide an expected behaviour to compare with ?

Comment: Why are people still injecting $scope into their controllers 5 years after Google started recommending to use controllerAs syntax or components and stop injecting $scope?

Comment: @AdrianBrand There are a lot of old tutorials out there that need to be updated or explicitly deprecated. When reading about AngularJS, it's hard to know whether or not what you're reading is still relevant.